# Get Tumbnail with google news rss feed using php

Tags: php, google-news

I can not get the tumbnail images using the following code. What i need to do to get a tumbnail images from google rss feed. Anyone can help me please ?

```
$news = simplexml_load_file('https://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=en&hl=en&topic=n&output=rss');

$feeds = array();

$i = 0;

foreach ($news->channel->item as $item) 
{
    preg_match('~<img[^>]*src\s?=\s?[\'"]([^\'"]*)~i',$item->description, $imageurl);
    //preg_match('@src="([^"]+)"@', $item->description, $imageurl);   
    $parts = explode('<font size="-1">', $item->description);

    $feeds[$i]['title'] = (string) $item->title;
    $feeds[$i]['link'] = (string) $item->link;
    $feeds[$i]['image'] = $imageurl[1];
    $feeds[$i]['site_title'] = strip_tags($parts[1]);
    $feeds[$i]['story'] = strip_tags($parts[2]);


    $i++;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($feeds);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: What do you mean with thumbnails? I did not see any property called like this in the feed.

Comment: @MarkusZeller tumbnails means news images you can see it in the feed `$feeds[$i]['image'] = $imageurl[1];` i can not get any results of image.

Comment: I can't find any "src" nor "img" string in your above feed => `curl 'https://news.google.com/news?pz=1&cf=all&ned=en&hl=en&topic=n&output=rss' -L -s | grep 'img\|src'` gives no result.

Comment: @Zeitounator the problem and question is this how to get image

Comment: There is no image. What do you want to get exactly ?

Comment: @Zeitounator how to get images,

Comment: What image ? We can go on for long like this.... You are giving the address of a feed that **does not contain a single image description**. How do you want us to give you a solution to find something that does not exist ?